# setArguments(args) is not resolvable when I creating a MainActivity newInstance method in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I am creating a newInstance method under Android's Activity class.

However, it will not recognize the setArgument method that accompanies the fragment.  Have you seen this before?

```
private static final String ARG_OPTION = "argument_option";

public static MainActivity newInstance (int option){
    MainActivity fragment = new MainActivity();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_OPTION, option);
    fragment.setArgument(args);
    return  fragment;

}
```

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

instead of

```
fragment.setArgument(args);
```